# Nft dont apper on metamask

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, nft, hardhat, erc-721

I minted contract and i see trasaction with nft on etherscan but on metamask profile I don't see any nft (same on opensea testnets) also on etherscan nft picture is blank how to fix this.

Transaction:
[image]

Code1:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "./nftestate.sol";

contract BidContract is REALESTATE {
    struct Bid {
        address bidder;
        uint amount;
    }
    address public ownerr;
    uint public highestBid;
    address public highestBidder;
    event newbid(uint256 indexed highestBid, address indexed highestBidder);

    mapping(address => Bid) public bids;

    constructor() {
        ownerr = msg.sender;
    }

    function hisghestbidcheck() public view returns (uint256) {
        return highestBid;
    }

    function bid() public payable {
        require(msg.value > highestBid, "Bid too low");

        if (highestBidder != address(0)) {
            payable(highestBidder).transfer(highestBid);
        }

        highestBid = msg.value;
        highestBidder = msg.sender;
        bids[msg.sender] = Bid(msg.sender, msg.value);
        emit newbid(highestBid, highestBidder);
    }

    function endAuction() public {
        require(msg.sender == ownerr, "Only owner can end auction");
        require(highestBidder != address(0), "No bids received");

        payable(ownerr).transfer(highestBid);
        highestBid = 0;
        safeMint(
            highestBidder,
            "ipfs://bafybeia435jagllnx7hgzidfd4q7jztp2u2a7di2h5xl6an6gbk5x6phzi"
        );
        highestBidder = address(0);
    }
}
```

Code 2:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.1;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract REALESTATE is ERC721, Ownable {
    constructor() ERC721("RealEsate", "RE") {}

    uint256 tokenId = 0;
    mapping(uint256 => string) private _tokenURIs;

    function _setTokenURI(string memory _tokenURI) internal virtual {
        require(
            _exists(tokenId),
            "ERC721URIStorage: URI set of nonexistent token"
        );
        _tokenURIs[tokenId] = _tokenURI;
    }

    function safeMint(address to, string memory _tokenURI) public onlyOwner {
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(_tokenURI);
    }
}
```